# How to add new values to existing dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a python dictionary that has a collection of keys with multiple values per key. I want to be able to add values to an existing key in the dictionary. I have reviewed multiple threads on this but I have not found one that applies directly.

Here is format of the key

```
{ "key1":{"value1-1 Attr": "value1-1","value1-2 Attr": "value1-2","value1-3 Attr": "value1-3", "Key2":{"value2-1 Attr": "value2-1","value2-2 Attr": "value2-2","value2-3 Attr": "value2-3",{} }
```

I want to be able to add new keys and also increase the value of existing key so I tried this Python code:

```
message1 = {"value1-4 Attr": "value1-4","value1-5 Attr": "value1-6","value1-7 Attr": "value1-7"}

if key in dictionary:
   dictionary[key].append(message1)
else:
    dictionary[key] =message1
```

The plan is to write the dictionary to a json file later. The problem is that I keep getting this error, which I'm not sure how to solve:

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

How could I fix the error and what is the best way to implement adding new value to existing key?

Comment: You're correctly assigning a value to a key in an existing dictionary in the `else` block, so you need to do something like that in the block above.

Comment: Try `dictionary[key].update(message1)` if key is found

Comment: First run the code to make sure your syntax is correct: check for errors caused by indentation, unclosed brackets, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using a list to store these values. There's no reason to have nested dicts here. Especially since you're just using append here.

Your data would then look like this:

```
data = {
  "key1":["value1-1", "value1-2","value1-3"],
  "Key2":["value2-1","value2-2", "value2-3"]}
```

Then you won't need an if statement just use `dict.setdefault`

```
data.setdefault(key, []).append(message)
```

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: You can `append` a value to a Python list (or array), but not to a dictionary.

---

#### Add `key: value` pair to dictionary

The syntax `dictionary[key] = message1` changes the existing value of `dictionary[key]` to `message` if the key is already in the dictionary, and creates a key-value pair `key: message1` if the key is not yet in the dictionary.

So instead of this...

```
if key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key].append(message1)
else:
    dictionary[key] = message1
```

...you would use this:

```
dictionary[key] = message1
```

---

#### Update dictionary with different `key: value` pairs

If you want to update a dictionary with the values from another dictionary, you can do it this way:

```
dictionary_1.update(dictionary_2)
```

This modifies `dictionary_1` in place, using the values for each key in `dictionary_2`.

If a key does not exist in `dictionary_1`, but exists in `dictionary_2`, then `update` will modify `dictionary_1` based on `dictionary_2`, so that  `dictionary_1` includes the key-value pair `key: dictionary_2[key]`.

Or, if a key exists in both `dictionary_1` and `dictionary_2`, then `update` will overwrite the existing value in `dictionary_1[key]` with the value from `dictionary_2[key]`.

So instead of this...

```
if key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key].append(message1)
else:
    dictionary[key] = message1
```

...you would use this:

```
dictionary[key].update(message1)
```

This works only if the value of `dictionary[key]` is a dictionary.

---

#### Append values to list within dictionary

If you want a key to have multiple values, you can store the multiple values in a list:

```
dictionary = {key: [value_1, value_2, value_3]}
```

Then you can append another value to the list:

```
dictionary[key].append(value_4)
```

Result:

```
dictionary = {key: [value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4]}
```

So instead of this...

```
if key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key].append(message1)
else:
    dictionary[key] = message1
```

...you would use this:

```
if key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key].append(message1)
else:
    dictionary[key] = [message1]
```

If `key` already exists in `dictionary`, this appends `message` to `dictionary[key]`. Otherwise, it creates a new single-item list `[message1]` as the value of `dictionary[key]`.

However, `dictionary[key].append(message1)` only works if the value of `dictionary[key]` is a list, *not* if the value is a dictionary.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if key in dictionary:
    dictionary[key] = dictionary[key] + message1
    print(dictionary[key])
else:
    dictionary[key] = message1
```